# why clearinterval() is not working inside useEffect with empty dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

**Output: incrementing the second value after 1 sec.................1....2...3....4 etc**
tell me why it's behaving like this i know another process to do that but why this process is not stopping the interval

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    const [Flag,setFlag]= useState(0);
    function inc() {
        setSeconds(seconds=>seconds + 1);
        setFlag(1);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        let interval = setInterval(inc, 1000);
        if(Flag===1)
        {
            console.log("inside");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

- We should add Flag as the useEffect dependency, otherwise useEffect won't know the Flag is changed to 1.
- We should store the setInterval timer to Ref variable

  ```
     const timer = useRef();
     const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
     const [Flag, setFlag] = useState(0);

     function inc() {
       setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
       setFlag(1);
     }

     useEffect(() => {
       if (Flag === 1) {
         if (timer.current) {
           clearInterval(timer.current);
         }
       } else {
         timer.current = setInterval(inc, 1000);
       }
     }, [Flag]);
  ```

Comment: clearInterval is also needed on unmount

Answer (score 0):

Why it is not stopping is simple:
`useEffect` callback runs only once (because empty dependency array makes it behave like `componentDidMount`). When that is run `Flag` is 0, so `clearInterval` is not run.